# Remove all labels and Set new list of labels Dynamically

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried updating the lables of a node Dynamically, but not succeeded. I want to remove all the labels of a node and then I wanted to set new list of labels to the same node.

My approach (failed, tried removing the labels only):

```
WITH ['a','b','c'] as newlabels
MATCH (n:people{name:'mam'}) 
WITH n,newlabels,labels(n) as oldlabels 
FOREACH (l in oldlabels | REMOVE n:l)
SET n:newlabels
RETURN labels(n)
```

I suspect that, the labels cant be changed dynamically using the references. Is my understanding correct? And how can we achieve this?

Comment: I am not quite sure if i understood your problem correctly but try this query. It can remove existing labels and apply the new one in one go.I am taking "NewLabel" as existing one and "Person" & "Profession" as the new one to be set. You can put your own conditions while matching. `match (n) REMOVE n:NewLabel SET n:Person:Profession return n`

Comment: If you dont know that the existing label is 'NewLabel', then how will you remove the label.

Answer (score 3):

No as you say dynamic labels modifications are not possible with raw cypher. Mainly because labels, property keys, relationship types are part of the query plan and used for caching.

There is the possibility to add labels dynamically with the APOC procedures, like explained here :

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_cypher_and_apoc_to_move_a_property_value_to_a_label

```
MATCH (n:Movie)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( id(n), [ n.genre ] ) YIELD node
REMOVE node.studio
RETURN node
```

Maybe a feature to replace/remove existing labels could be a nice addition to the APOC.

**UPDATE**

After checking the source of APOC, there is a setLabels procedure which will remove non-matching passed labels, for example :

```
WITH ["A","B"] as labels
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH collect(id(m))[0..20] as movies, labels
CALL apoc.create.setLabels(movies, labels) YIELD node RETURN node, labels(node)


│node                          │labels(node)│
╞══════════════════════════════╪════════════╡
│{tagline: Prepare to enter a s│[B, A]      │
│ecret world of assassins, titl│            │
│e: Ninja Assassin, released: 2│            │
│009}                          │            │
├──────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│{tagline: Walk a mile you'll n│[B, A]      │
│ever forget., title: The Green│            │
│ Mile, released: 1999}        │            │
├──────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│{tagline: 400 million people w│[B, A]      │
│ere waiting for the truth., ti│            │
│tle: Frost/Nixon, released: 20│            │
│08}                           │            │
├──────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│{tagline: He didn't want law. │[B, A]      │
│He wanted justice., title: Hof│            │
│fa, released: 1992}           │            │
├──────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
```

Problem solved :)